# It's possible to use a Mac invited account with firmware password enabled?

Tags: mac, firmware, firmware-password

I have the firmware protection enabled on my Mac, but whit this property I can't use the guest account of the computer without ingress the firmware password. I'd like to avoid this password request for guests (and obviously, for the primary boot) and maintain the firmware password for boot on others partitions, such as the recuperation mode.

Answer (score 1):

Firmware password prevents the startup of any disk other than the designated startup disk, so it should not prevent startup of guest or other accounts.As long as the account is using your startup disk, it should not ask for the firmware password.

However, if you have file vault enabled, guest accounts can only access Safari, and the network connection. File vault encrypts the hard drive (SSD), preventing the guest from accessing it. If file vault is off, guest accounts function like a normal account with limited permissions.

Comment: Sorry, I omited FileVault configuration and it’s an important fact. I use FileVault option, so efectively guest account access only to Safari mode. But before launch this, firmware password is required.